# Boostrap page only responsive when changing the width, but not the height of the browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I created this page with bootstrap but it only responsive when I am changing the size of the browser's width. When I am changing the height of the browser, it is not responsive. What I did wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fullname">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control"/>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="comments" name="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="luckynumber">Lucky Number</label>
        <select name="luckynumber" id="luckynumber" class="form-control">
            <option>double zero</option>
            <option>seven</option>
            <option>thirteen</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="dog"/>Own a dog</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="cat"/>Own a cat</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="owned"/>Owned by a cat</label>
        </div>


        <span><b>Your favorite weather?</b></span><br/>

        <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="count" value="hot"/>hot</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="count" value="cold"/>cold</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="count" value="rainy"/>rainy</label>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you need responsive change on height (the bootstrap rules is just to width changes ), Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is based on media queries.

For example:

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
```

It depends only on the width.

If you want use it by height check this response: [Twitter Bootstrap 3 responsive full height grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220146/twitter-bootstrap-3-responsive-full-height-grid)

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap framework responsiveness is based on the viewport width, not height. You will have to use your own approach to handle this. Perhaps setting the `body` and `html` in your css to `height: 100%` may be a start. But as I said, with Bootstrap alone, you won't be able to create responsiveness based in the height of the viewport.